# HTML5 player fallback is not working on MAC and Windows 8 OS Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Below is my code:

```
var test_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var canvascheck = (test_canvas.getContext) ? true : false;
var BrowsercheckPlayer = false;
var testEl = document.createElement("video"), h264;
if (testEl.canPlayType) {
h264 = "" !== (testEl.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'));
BrowsercheckPlayer = h264;
}

if (canvascheck && BrowsercheckPlayer) 
{
Load HTML5 Player
}
else
{
Load Flash player
}
```

Iam using 2 players in my application (Html5 Player and Flash Player).

In my project im using Only Mp4 videos.

If the Browser supports the html5 player means I have loaded the Html5 player otherwise it load flash player.In my code I have checked two conditions 1 for browser support the video tag or not and another one is mp4 video is playing in browser or not. My code is working fine in all OS.

But in MAC and Win 8 os not working in firefox

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: If you're actually using JW Player, there's no need for any of this. It automatically uses the HTML5 <video> tag if the browser supports it, and falls back to Flash if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why this question is tagged as jwplayer.